# Device Information in feedback email android

Tags: java, android

I have quotes application which have function for send feedback email to developer. I want attach **device model and Android version information** in email. I do not know how  can I do this. My java code for send email is like below.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","exmaple@gmail.com", null));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Write Here");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to send info to developers email?

Comment: for get suggestion from user as well bug report :)

Comment: if you want to report bugs, consder using https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics crashlytics

Comment: you can also give ACRA a try. https://github.com/ACRA/acra

Comment: ... and what happens when you run the code?  Error? Runs successfully, but does not send an email? What?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following code

```
String deviceInfo="Device Info:";
deviceInfo += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
deviceInfo += "\n OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
deviceInfo += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
deviceInfo += "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " ("+ android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto","exmaple@gmail.com", null));
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Device Info");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, deviceInfo);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: HI Sir ! What is s in this ? I am getting error like "s cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: i have updated the code. Try now

Comment: Thanks ! Its working fine now

Answer (score 2):

You can get device information from the "Build" object, so Build.MODEL gives you a string of the device model, Build.MANUFACTURER gives you the manufacturers name etc.. The SDK is an integer though, you don't get a string, so you need to do something different for that to get a string.